# Does hibernate named query prevents SQL Injection attack?

Tags: hibernate, security, sql-injection

Does Named Query feature of Hibernate helps to prevent SQL Injection attack? I am defining named queries in hbm.xml file not as annotation.

```
I am working on a Flex-Hibernate-JBoss application
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Read this [How to avoid SQL injection in Hibernate](http://blog.harpoontech.com/2008/10/how-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-hibernate.html) and [How to Fix SQL Injection in Hibernate](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-hibernate).